# UE4 pathfinding without turning around as in Pacman

Tags: unreal-engine4, path-finding, unreal-blueprint

I am making a 3D Pacman Game using `Blueprints` and the UE4 standard `NavMesh` pathfinding algorithm. It works all fine, but I can't get the pathfinding to **prevent 180 degree turns**. In Pacman, the ghosts can't directly turn around and have to find another path instead. Does anyone have an idea how to achieve this? (im a complete path finding Noob)

Comment: You could try placing an object behind each ghost (collidable by only the "owning" ghost) This should work by blocking the path behind each ghost. It is not a perfect solution, but its quick :)

Comment: I tried, but my performance was really struggeling, becaus the navigation area had to reload all the time. Thank you anyway